# What's the cheapest way to specialize a traits member

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, type-traits, c++03

I have a traits class that is supposed to provide just one information about other types (in form of a string):

```
template<typename T>
struct some_traits {
    static const char* const some_string;
};
```

I need to provide special instances of `some_string` for each type. The common way I know how to do this is to only declare `some_traits`, and then write specializations:

```
template<typename T>
struct some_traits;

template<>
struct some_traits<blah> {
    static const char* const some_string;
};
const char* const some_traits<blah>::some_string = "blah string";
```

This is, however, a lot of code, when all I need is a specialized `some_string`. Is there a way to simplify this?

I have tried to fiddle with explicit specializations, but failed to come up with a syntax that doesn't make the compiler spit venomous error messages into my face.

*Notes:*

- I know I can hide this behind a macro. I am still curious.
- This needs to compile on an embedded platform with GCC 4.1. So C++03 is all we have. (Boost is fine, but for limited Posix support we're stuck with 1.52, in case this matters.)

Comment: You only need full specializations? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d47849e14289149b

Comment: how many specializations do you need?

Comment: @dyp: Yeah, that would do. I thought you cannot specialize class template members?

Comment: (BTW; @dyp, if you turn this comment into an answer, you will get an upvote from me, and an accept, if nobody else brings up anything better.)

Comment: You can explicitly specialize members of "class templates". Note explicit specialization requires that all enclosing templates are resolved to actual types/functions, so you actually (re)define the member of a specific class (template instantiation) rather than a member of a generic (uninstantiated) class template.

Comment: Is your job kind of equivalent to the implementation's job when defining `numeric_limits`, where you need to specialize each type to reflect its characteristics?

Comment: @black I seem to do traits at least once a year, and the conditions vary. But for this one, yes, every type that should be usable needs to have its own specialization of `some_string`.

Comment: Then you can't do much. `#define specialize(type, value) template <> char const *const some_traits< type >::some_string = value;` works, but you still need to go through all the specialized types.

Comment: @black Enumerating all of them isn't much of a hassle. It's just that I was curious if you really had to write such an amount of code for each one – even if I can hide it behind such a macro (which I have).

Comment: @dyp: After chewing on it for a while, I now believe what you are saying in your last comment basically means I cannot just _declare_ the primary and then add member specializations, but I have to actually _define_ it. Is that correct?

Comment: @sbi Yes: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f81bc1a372008937 An explicit specialization of a member has to specialize an existing member. (That unspecialized member needs a declaration, but no definition.)

Comment: @dyp Thanks, now I got it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to explicitly specialize members of class templates:

```
template<typename T>
struct some_traits {
    static const char* const some_string;
};

template<>
char const* const some_traits<int>::some_string = "int";
```

This should reduce the overhead of declaring new specializations slightly. However, this technique cannot be applied to partial specializations:

```
template<typename T> struct foo {};
template<typename T>
char const* const some_traits<foo<T>>::some_string = "foo<T>"; // error
```

... that is, unless you add a partial specialization for `some_traits`:

```
template<typename T>
struct some_traits<foo<T>> {
    char const* const some_string;
};
```

---

Two alternatives:

(1) Using ADL and functions

```
template<typename T> struct some_string_tag {};

template<typename T>
struct some_traits {
    static const char* const some_string;
};
template<typename T>
char const* const some_traits<T>::some_string = get_string(some_string_tag<T>());
```

A specialization can then be written as:

```
char const* get_string(some_string_tag<int>) { return "int"; }
```

And partial specializations as:

```
template<typename T>
char const* get_string(some_string_tag<foo<T>>) { return "foo<T>"; }
```

(In this case, `some_traits` is a point for customizing how the string is found, and it provides convenient access to the string as a variable.)

(2) A second trait using an inline function

```
template<typename T>
char const* const some_traits<T>::some_string = some_traits_X<T>::get_string();

template<typename T> struct some_traits_X {
    // provide: static char const* get_string();
};

template<>
struct some_traits_X<int> {
    static char const* get_string() { return "int"; }
};

template<typename T>
struct some_traits_X<foo<T>> {
    static char const* get_string() { return "foo<T>"; }
};
```

Comment: I have found that, in general, constants are more universally useful than function calls (see `std::numeric_limits<>::max()`). It might well be that with strings it doesn't make that much of a difference, but I wanted to know how to do this anyway.

Comment: @sbi It was meant as a second trait, just to provide the string. You can still your original trait as an "adapter". See my updated answer. This might be more convenient if you have several traits which all need specialization.

Comment: I see. Pretty comprehensive, this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Why not use functions?

```
template<typename T>
struct some_traits {
    static const char* const some_string();
};

template<>
struct some_traits<blah> {
     static const char* const some_string() { return "blah string"; }
};
```

Comment: Because a constant is, in general, more universally usable than a function call? (BTW; if I'd do this, I'd only _declare_ the primary template, and wouldn't _define_ it.)